# Display only text files openfiledialog

Tags: c#

I want to know how to filter out all files that are not txt files in the open dialog in c#. I have been playing with this for ages and had no joy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the filter property:  [MSDN Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sstem.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx)

Here is a MSDN Walk through on how to Customize [OpenFile Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx)

Here is an example:

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "Text|*.txt|All|*.*";
```

You can remove `All` if you dont want to give them an option to select other types of files:

Comment: Thanks i didnt realise that the things being displayed when using the filter were internet shortcuts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the .Filter property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx

Or did i misunderstand you?

Answer (score 1):

`OpenFileDialog.Filter` property.

Documentation - [MSDN OpenFileDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)